# Can't get Core Bluetooth to work in Swift iOS playground

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am new to swift.  I am not able to get a callback to centralManagerDidUpdateState:: w/ following in playground (i.e.: i thought initialization would call back into centralManagerDidUpdateState):

```
import CoreBluetooth
class BTDiscovery:NSObject,
CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
        println("here")
    }
}

var bt = BTDiscovery()
```

---

Is Core Bluetooth supporting in the iOS Swift playground?
I tried this for OSX playground and IOBluetooth.  This also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're running into is the playground is inherently synchronous while the BlueTooth discovery is asynchronous.  To allow it to work you need to add some things to your playground to allow asynchronous operation:

```
import XCPlayground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
```

Also note that since the iOS playground is run on the simulator, I wouldn't necessarily expect CB to work there at all.

You also have more fundamental problems in that you're not doing anything to actually trigger discovery.  You need to create an instance of `CBCentralManager` and use it to drive the discovery process:

```
import Cocoa
import XCPlayground
import CoreBluetooth

class BTDiscovery:NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
        println("here")
    }

}

var bt = BTDiscovery()
var central = CBCentralManager(delegate: bt, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  The only correction on your comment - there is no discovery yet because i wanted to see if the initialization (var bt = BTDiscovery() got a DidUpdateState .  When it didn't, I realized something wasn't working.  It wasn't working on OSX with IOBluetooth.  I will now try again.  I agree w/ your point re: simulator /no Core Bluetooth support.  Again, THANK YOU.

Comment: didUpdateState won't be called in your example because without the CBCentralManager, there's nothing to call it (in addition to the asynchronous issues)

Answer (score 2):

You can only use Core Bluetooth on an actual iOS device; it is not supported in the simulator, and by extension, it is not supported in a Playground as this is also executing on your Mac rather than on an iOS device.

Comment: This is correct answer, Core Bluetooth works only on device, so you can't use it in playgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Either `XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely` nor `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution` will work.

Please keep in mind CoreBluetooth only works on device. Which means currently it won't work on the Playground.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use Bluetooth in Swift Playground. Please note you have to use `PlaygroundBluetooth`. You can find more informations about it here [Documentation Framework PlaygroundBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundbluetooth)

This is how you can scan using the central.

```
let managerDelegate: PlaygroundBluetoothCentralManagerDelegate = <# manager delegate instance #>

let manager = PlaygroundBluetoothCentralManager(services: nil)
manager.delegate = managerDelegate
```

Please note `PlaygroundBluetooth` is just a subset of `CoreBluetooth` therefore you can not do everything which is normally possible in `CoreBluetooth`, but I think it's still great for simple things to have fun with.